How to prevent reinitializing double
I use Tempus dominus (https://getdatepicker.com) and I've some date pickers inside on each row of a table (one per row)
Now each row can be (dynamically) modified, added or deleted with a button.
Then, when I add a new row, I call a function to initialize all date fields on each row, using a common class of course:
$("#add").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  bind_all_date_in_table();
});

I need to reinit all rows cause I have other button to import rows (more than one) from another document...
     function bind_all_date_in_table() {

         $(#table).forEach(function (row) {
            
            let dateinput = row.querySelector(".dateinput");
            
            const dateinputPicker = new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(dateinput);

            dateinputPicker.subscribe("change.td", (e) => {
                
                ... do something / operation with this row ....
                
            });

         });
     }

Then problem is that if I add 5 rows... then "dateinput" is initialized 5 times (i find it based on shadow of the picker... every time bind_all_date_in_table() is called, the shadow became more dark (more pickers overlying)....
I ask: is there a way to check if a dateinput is already initialized before calling new tempusDominus.TempusDominus ... ?
